# Bootstrap table follow scroll inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cakephp-3.0

I have a table inside a div that shows some important information about the elements inside the div and I want this table to follow the scroll as long as the div.

```
<div id="DivMeritos" class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-19 ">
           <div class="table-responsive">
              <table>
                <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <th class="fill"><h2>Meritos</h2></th>
                    <th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                        <h2>Auto Puntuación</h2>
                        <input type="text" value="<?= $solicitude->autoPuntuacion ?>" size="2" disabled>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                        <h2>Puntuación Evaluación</h2>
                        <input type="text" id="puntuacion" value="<?= $solicitude->puntuacionEvaluacion ?>" size="2" disabled>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>        
            </div>
                <div class="list-group"> <!-- <a class="list-group-item active"> -->                    
                 {code .....}
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried everything that I found about making an element follow the scroll with Javascript/jQuery with no result.

I´m working with Bootstrap v3.3 and Cakephp v3.5.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: do you mean you want the table fixed (sticky) while scroll the div

Comment: scroll horizintall or vertical?

Comment: what this `col-lg-19 `???????????

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes, that´s what I mean. I want the table to stay fixed while scroll the div. But just that div, no the rest of the page. Scroll vertical. col-lg-19 has something to do with responsive clases in Bootstrap.

Comment: but  `col-lg-19 ` does not exsit in bootstrap the max is 12(`col-lg-12`)

Answer (score 0):

Use  `position: fixed;`

See code below:

```css
    .panel-body{
        height: 150px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding:0!important;
    }
    .table-responsive{
        position: fixed;
        width:90%!important;
        
    }
    .list-group{
    height: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <div id="DivMeritos" class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class=" col-md-12">
               <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table> 
    </div>
     <div class="list-group"> <!-- <a class="list-group-item active"> -->                      

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!